# How to Change Position of DIV Video element using CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, youtube

On this page, you can see the embedded video at the end of the post. (http://viralinindia.net/narendra-modi/positive-news-journalist-megyn-kelly-insults-tea-seller-modi/14806/)

now I want to put that video above the title using `CSS` because I have put the video manually in end of every post and it's not possible to change every post.

the site is on WordPress.

any idea?

Comment: This can't be done with CSS. You would have to use Javascript/jQuery to manipulate the dom structure. Alternatively you could attempt to use SQL to modify all the posts in your database, however I imagine this would be quite tricky.

Comment: can u tell me how can do this using java?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really want to write the code for you :) But you would need something like `$("#source").appendTo("#destination");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try, but without changing the HTML structure in the first place it can easily break. You should also take care about lower resolutions (RWD) altering the CSS code further.

But to give the idea (which is a bad idea) you could try something like:

```
.video-container {
    position: absolute; /* position it absolutely */
    top: 0;
    width: 640px;
}

.theiaPostSlider_slides {
    position: initial; /* let the .video-container break out of the relative wrapper */
}

.td-post-header {
    padding-top: 500px; /* give the video some place at the top */
}
```

Comment: love u bro, its working, can u please tell me how to make the video now responsive, because its showing in full size on mobile?

Comment: i have made the video responsive but its breaking few things.

Comment: You should look in the CSS for the media queries breakpoints - like `@media (max-width: 767px) {}` and there add proper widths for the video container. The video container is now positioned absolutely and that causes more troubles to the RWD - that is why it would be better to change the page structure instead of working on CSS alone.

Comment: http://viralinindia.net/videos/ravish-kumar-slams-bjp-minister-kiran-rijuju-joota-wala-comment/9637/?fsf check now everything is FIXED. Thanks a lot bro